# How to use Observables instead of Events to listen to dismiss event in Angular Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, observable, ionic5

I'm using ionic's inline modal, [which's triggered by a boolean](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#using-isopen). However, when the modal is dismissed, the boolean is not automatically set to zero. According to ionic's documentation, "Developers should listen for the `ionModalDidDismiss` or `didDismiss` event and set `isOpen` to `false`. Unfortunately, they provide no further information on how to do so. Ionic had an `Events` module, but it was deprecated in exchange for using Observables. And now I'm stuck.

I tried to look for sources that explain how observables could be used in lieu of ionic's Events but to no avail. To summarize: I want to listen to a DOM dismiss event from ionic-modal and then set the `isOpen` boolean that triggers the modal to false. How can I use Observables to listen to events? What alternatives are there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need to use observables, I think it's as simple as setting a variable to `false`:

```html
<ion-modal (ionModalDidDismiss)="isModalOpen = false">
  ...
</ion-modal>
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried that but I have the modal in a separate component, so it doesn't work. I need somehow to share this variable between the two components. I'm currently using one-way binding to send from parent to child. I could do two-way binding but I think it beats the purpose, since Ionic could've but didn't implement it this to prevent internals from being tightly coupled.

Comment: Didn't you say you were using "inline modal" ?

Comment: Yes, inline, but supplied using its selector in a parent component. I ended up using Output and Eventemitter. But I guess your answer is a correct one.

Comment: Okay cool  I just whipped up [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-74944463?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmy-modal%2Fmy-modal.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmy-modal%2Fmy-modal.component.ts) doing the same thing :-)